# DoublyLinkedList getting data from node

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have created a Doubly Linked List, and I am trying to call the getData method from the Linked List. However it is not working. I am trying to get this from the node. Here is the code from the Node.

```
    private class Node<AnyType> 
{

    AnyType data;
    Node<AnyType> next;
    Node<AnyType> previous;

    //Creates the Node with the parameters of data next and previous
    public Node(AnyType data,Node<AnyType> next, Node<AnyType> previous )
    {

        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;

    }

    //Getters and setters for data next and previous
    public AnyType getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node<AnyType> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node<AnyType> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setData(AnyType data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<AnyType> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Node<AnyType> previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}
```

It may be a problem that it says that setData(AnyType data), is never used locally, however im not sure on that.

Now to where im trying to use the getData method. This is in an animate method,

```
    if (USE_LINKED_LIST)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.linked_list.size(); i++)
        {
            Movable current = this.linked_list.getData();
            current.move(frame_rate_duration);

            if(current.dead())
            {
                this.linked_list.remove(current);
                i--;
            }

        }
    }
```

The this.linked_list.getData() is giving me the error saying I must create method getData() in DoublyLinkedList. Im sure this is just a simple error but anything helps! thanks!

Here is the entire LinkedList class

```
package Our_Fireworks;

/**
* 
* @author Ben Hammond
*
* @param <AnyType>
*/


public class DoublyLinkedList <AnyType>
{
private Node<AnyType> header;
private Node<AnyType> footer;

public DoublyLinkedList() 
{
    //Creates the header Node with data set to null, next set to footer, previous set to null
    header = new Node<AnyType>(null, footer, null);

    footer = new Node<AnyType>(null, null, header);


}

// Creates the insert method used to insert a Node into the linked list
public void insert(AnyType data)
{
    //Creates a new node to insert before the footer
    Node<AnyType> newNode = new Node<AnyType>(data, footer, footer.previous);
    //Sets the node previous to footer, to link to the new Node
    footer.previous.setNext(newNode);
    //Sets the footer node to be linked to the new Node
    footer.setPrevious(newNode);
}

//Remove method to remove a Node from the linked list
public void remove (AnyType data)
{
    //Starts the iteratorLooper from the first Node in the list
    Iterator<AnyType> iteratorLooper = first();

    //Runs the while loop as long as valid = true 
    while(iteratorLooper.valid())
    {
        //Once you receive the correct data, the loop will stop
        if(iteratorLooper.getData().equals(data))
        {
            break;
        }
        //Goes to the next data member 
        iteratorLooper.next();
    }

    //Once the while loop breaks, it will delete that data member
    iteratorLooper.remove();

}

//Creates the size method
public int size()
{
    //Creates an int variable
    int count = 0;
    //Starts the iteratorLooper at the first Node
    Iterator<AnyType> iteratorLooper = first();

    //As long as valid returns true the while loop will run
    while(iteratorLooper.valid())
    {
        //Will add to the count variable
        count++;
        //Goes to the next Node
        iteratorLooper.next();
    }
    //Returns the count once the while loop is complete
    return count;

}

//Creates the first method
public Iterator<AnyType> first()
{
    //Creates a new Iterator, at header.next
    Iterator<AnyType> newIterator = new Iterator<AnyType>(header.next);
    //Returns the Iterator
    return newIterator;
}
//Creates the last method
public Iterator<AnyType> last()
{
    //Creates a new Iterator at footer.previous
    Iterator<AnyType> newIterator = new Iterator<AnyType>(footer.previous);
    //Returns the Iterator
    return newIterator;
}

//Iterator find method
public Iterator<AnyType> find(AnyType data)
{

    Iterator<AnyType> iteratorLooper = first();
    //As long as valid returns true the while loop runs
    while(iteratorLooper.valid())
    {
        //runs the loop until data is equal to "getData"
        if(iteratorLooper.getData().equals(data))
        {
            break;
        }

        iteratorLooper.next();
    }

    //Returns iteratorLooper
    return iteratorLooper;




}

//Creates the Node class
private class Node<AnyType> 
{

    AnyType data;
    Node<AnyType> next;
    Node<AnyType> previous;

    //Creates the Node with the parameters of data next and previous
    public Node(AnyType data,Node<AnyType> next, Node<AnyType> previous )
    {

        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;

    }

    //Getters and setters for data next and previous
    public AnyType getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node<AnyType> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node<AnyType> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setData(AnyType data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<AnyType> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Node<AnyType> previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}


//Creates the Iterator class
public class Iterator<AnyType>
{
    //Creates a new node of currentNode
    private Node<AnyType> currentNode;

    public Iterator(Node<AnyType> currentNode)
    {
        this.currentNode = currentNode;
    }

    //Creates the valid method
    public boolean valid()
    {
        //Checks to see if current node is not equal to the header footer, or null
        if (currentNode != header && currentNode != footer && currentNode != null)
                {
                    //If the statement is true it returns true
                    return true;

                }
        else
                {
                    //If it is not true... it simply returns false
                    return false;
                }

    }
    //Creates the next method
    public void next()
    {
        //Checks if the next Node is not equal to null
        if(currentNode.getNext() != null)
        {
            //Gets the next node, of what ever the current node is
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();    
        }
    }
    //Creates the previous method
    public void previous()
    {
        //Checks if the previous Node is not equal to null
        if(currentNode.getPrevious() != null)
        {
            //Gets the previous node of currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.getPrevious();
        }
    }

    public AnyType getData()
    {
        //Gets the data inside the currentNode
        return currentNode.getData();
    }

    //Creates the remove method
    public void remove()
    {
        //As long as valid returns true than the if statement will run
        if(valid())
        {
        currentNode.getPrevious().setNext(currentNode.getNext());

        currentNode.getNext().setPrevious(currentNode.getPrevious());
        currentNode = currentNode.getPrevious();
        }


    }

    //Creates the insert method with the parameters of AnyType and data
    public void insert(AnyType data)
    {
        //Creates a newNode to be inserted after currentNode
        Node<AnyType> newNode = new Node<AnyType>(data, currentNode.next, currentNode );


        currentNode.getNext().setPrevious(newNode);
        currentNode.setNext(newNode);

    }

   }










    }
```

Comment: Do you have a class called `AnyType` somewhere or do you want the type to be anything?

Comment: I do not have a class called AnyType, I would like it to be anything.

Comment: Post the code for your `DoublyLinkedList` since that seems to be the class that is missing the method.

Comment: @Takendarkk `AnyType` is the type variable of the generic class.

Comment: @BenHammond Your `DoublyLinkedList` class doesn't have the method `getData()`, only your `Node` class does.

Comment: @Takendarkk So would i insert a getData method before Node? Like maybe under  public DoublyLinkedList()? and what would the getData return?

Answer (score 1):

You have `getData()` method for `Node`, not for your linked list class. I think you meant something like

```
Movable current = this.linked_list.get(i).getData();
```

(Provided your linked list class has a getter for index)

Usually linked lists don't have random access getters, so most likely the whole code should be written differently:

```
for (Node<Movable> node = linked_list.getHead(); node != null; node = node.getNext()) {
    Movable current = node.getData();
    ...
}
```

EDIT: So you have getData() in your `Iterator`:

```
for (Iterator<Movable> iter = linked_list.first(); iter.valid(); iter.next()) {
    Movable current = iter.getData();
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I do that, i get the same error, it just says to create get(int) method in DoublyLinkedList

Comment: @BenHammond because there isn't, check my answer. And you should provide the code for `DoublyLinkedList` if you want precise answer.

Comment: I added the entire DoyblyLinkedList if you would like to check over that and see where the error might be

Comment: If i do that, it gives an error that Iterator<Movable> must be qualified with a parameterized type since it is not static.

Comment: @BenHammond make it static?